# Coarse grained remote interface vs encapsulating business logic

Tags: web-services, interfaces

I'm writing a Web Service that will be consumed by a Mobile client.

The Mobile client has to make several chained requirements checks to determine whether the user may initiate a request, and if so what type.  If any of the checks fail then the user is redirected to a UI explaining why.

I can't decide whether I should expose an operation for each check on my Web Service, or expose a single coarse-grained interface that simply returns all the check value results in a single DTO.

Is the coarse-grained interface premature optimisation? I can always provide both the fine-grained and coarse-grained interfaces because the coarse-grained interface will use the local fine-grained methods to build its DTO.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what the checks actually are and how they will be used.

If the checks will always occur together, then you should only expose a single method that does all of the checks.

If individual checks will be needed separately, then of course you will need individual methods available.  You might also want a single method that does them all together, depending on how complicated that is.

Answer (score 1):

No, it isn't.

Optimization means changing the implementation of a bit of code so that it does the same thing, runs faster, and is harder to read or write. (And premature means doing it before you know that it will speed things up, and that a speed-up is needed here.)

What you propose are two different, fairly equally complicated ways of doing things, so whether to choose one or the other depends on the operations you'll likely need. If you may need all the checks anyway, and computing and returning them all together isn't obviously much more cumbersome, then there isn't any reason not to do that in the first place - it's just good common sense.

Answer (score 1):

Both. It's a question of [Single Responsibiliy Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)

That is; you need the coarse grained ones to meet requirements for use cases it sounds like you're saying, and you need the fine grained ones that the coarse grained ones will rely on.

My suggestion: Expose them both, and do so well separated in different classes. If you only expose the coarse grained ones, you're not putting a boundary between the coarse and fine grained work. In the future this may likely result in the multiple individual responsibilities of the fine grained work bleeding into the coarse grained ones which would be an SRP violation.

So:

**Expose them both to ensure the boundary's are maintained, and you have clean separation of concerns and responsibilities.**

Comment: I disagree with making this an absolute rule. It depends the complexity of the problem and how flexibly the underlying functions need to be used.  Rote application of rules like SRP, without regard for whether abstraction is needed, leads to death by design in my opinion.  Those principles should be used *when they actually help*, rather than all the time. A good rule of thumb to start with is: will this abstraction make my code cleaner, or will it make it more complicated?

Comment: @dan1111 True, use common sense, but if a question like this one is coming up I would presume that indicates there is a level of complexity differentiating the two sets of functionality. If there wasn't, he would have just tossed it together without thinking about implementing this separation.

Comment: Fair enough, but in my experience over-design is a common problem (and the OP seems worried about whether this is over-design).

Comment: @dan1111 and in my experience under-design is a common problem where people claim KISS is the answer even if it violates well known good practices, and then they wonder why a year later the code is a mess of random hacks. It's not always you have the time to do things with clean boundaries, you'll be better off doing them that way when you do have that time so that when you don't have the time, they're already in place to keep you honest.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you on that as well.  It is hard to achieve the right balance.